# Call back methods with sqlite in node js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new program using node.js which reads SQLite DB and creates a XML document. I created some sub methods, and when I'm trying to return the DB result using a callback method its not passing anything.

Method to read and create xml part:

```
function dbpic(id,callback){
      dd = db1.all("SELECT * FROM pictures left join item_pics on item_pics.picid=pictures.picid where item_pics.itemid = "+id+"", function(err1,rows1){
            var ee = '';
            rows1.forEach(function(row1) {
                ee += '<picture>';
                    ee+='<picturename>'+row1.pic+'</picturename>';
                    ee+='<link>'+row1.url+'</link>';
                ee += '</picture>';
            }); 
            console.log(ee);
            callback( ee);
        });
}
```

Calling this method using:

```
dbpic(row.iid,function(df){
    ss += df;
});
```

Variable `ss` is going to display, but it gets nothing from callback method. Database contains relevant data and returning correct results results. I checked them using `console.log`.

When i logged `df` with console, it displays results correctly. but `ss` is not stored `df`'s data.

Comment: I'd guess you try to print out `ss` before the callback is completed.

Comment: actually im calling it after calling dbpic method. i am adding some text to ss variable before run dbpic method. and those are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments you have some troubles understanding the asynchronous concept. This how things happen in your code.

```
// STEP 1
ss = "initalvalue";
dbpic(row.iid,function(df){
    // STEP 3, 4, 5, 6 ...
    ss += df;
});
// STEP 2
ss += "ending";
```

You need to wait until the last callback is called until you display the results.

Comment: i got it now the idea. can you give me some solution to correct it?

Comment: Add another layer of functions with a callback. In the long term take a look at flow control libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: sorry, i did not clear those samples. can someone give some samples?